# Find Sum with Window

Tags: java, algorithm

I was trying to solve this problem:
There is a list and a window. The window says the number of elements to be added in the list, for example:

`[4, 2, 73, 11, -5]` and window size `2` should return `[6, 75, 84, 6]`.

So I wrote the code as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    LinkedList<Integer> l=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    l.add(5);
    l.add(8);
    l.add(9);
    l.add(3);
    l.add(4);
    l.add(1);
    int window=2;
    int[] sum=new int[l.size()-window+1];

    for(int i=0;i<=l.size()-window; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<window; j++){
            sum[i]=sum[i]+l.get(i+j);
        }
    }
}
```

This does not an efficient solution as time complexity is high. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to better performance by recognizing that as the window slides from one index to the next, the only difference between one sum and the next sum is that exactly one item is added and exactly one item is subtracted.

You don't need to re-compute the sum in a `j` `for` loop in each iteration of the `i` `for` loop.  Compute the initial sum of the first `window` numbers first, which will take care of `i` being `0`.  Then in each iteration of the `i` loop, starting at `1`, add in to the sum the value at index `window + i` and subtract out the value at index `i`.  This will improve the performance, especially for high values of `window`.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to solve this is instead of doing two loops to get the partial sum in the window, you can save each sum result in a variable called `current`. Then every time you shift the window to the right, one element is shifted out and a new element is shifted in. So you can just update the windowed sum by adding the new shift-in element and subtracting the old shift-out element. This way you save some computation. The overall time complexity is O(N). Code is listed below.

```
   public class WindowSum {
        public static int[] windowSum(int[] arr, int windowSize) {
            int[] sum = new int[arr.length-windowSize+1];
            int current = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<windowSize; i++)
                current += arr[i];
            sum[0] = current;
            for(int i=1; i<arr.length-windowSize+1; i++) {
                sum[i] = current + arr[i+windowSize-1] - arr[i-1];
                current = sum[i];
            }
            return sum;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] num = {4, 2, 73, 11, -5};
            int[] sum = windowSum(num, 2);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework problem, so I'll just give a hint about algorithm, not actual code:

- First, compute the answer for the first window.  Save it in the `0`th slot.
- For each next step, move the window one to the right: add the new integer that falls into the window, and subtract the old one.  Save it in the next slot.
- Repeat until the end of the window hits the end of your input data.